# How to store result from getJSON?

Tags: arrays, store, getjson

I use an array passing into the function to store data from result of getJSON, however, it always return nothing. Is there anyway to store the data return from getJSON into an array?
getHashImages(tagVals[0], 5, imagesToParse);

```
function getHashImages(tag, count, result) {
        // Clear all images
        $('ul.images').html('');

        var url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'+tag+'/media/recent?&client_id=5a7b13571ced47418dd539e6fc97a67f&count='+count+'&callback=?';
        document.writeln('In function the length of ' + result.length + '<br />');
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            console.log(data.data.length);

            if(data.data.length === 0){
            //  $('ul.images').append('<li>No results</li>');
            } else {        
                $.each(data.data, function(index, value){
                    //console.log(value);
                    var imgUrl = value.images.low_resolution.url,
                        imgUser = value.user.username,
                        imgLink = value.link;
                        result.push(imgLink);
                        document.writeln('In function the length of ' + result.length + 'after JSON <br />');
                    //$('ul.images').append('<li><a href="'+imgLink+'" target="_blank"><img src="'+imgUrl+'"/></a></li>');
                });
            }

        });
        document.writeln('In function the length of ' + result.length + 'after JSON <br />');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to indicate the name of the callback function to Instagram's API.

> var url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'+tag+'/media/recent?&client_id=5a7b13571ced47418dd539e6fc97a67f&count='+count+'&callback=myCallback';

Then you implement a function myCallback( obj ) which will retrieve an object returned by the API. To see what the object looks like, you can just open it [in your browser](https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/lol/media/recent?&client_id=5a7b13571ced47418dd539e6fc97a67f&count=5&callback=myCallback).

See Wikipedia page for [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) for further explanations.

Comment: Hi, Ben, I want to store the data each time returned from getJSON to an array, but the data only exist within the scope of getJSON, I want to get those data out of the scope.